# Tomcat server stopped but eclipse says ports are still in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have stopped my Tomcat 7.0 server in Eclipse. When I go to the server view, it has confirmed that the tomcat server has stopped. Yet any time I try to run a new project on the Tomcat Server, I get the error

"Several Ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use..." How do I get tomcat server to run my java project?

Comment: Try `netstat -an` to check if some process is using port 8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to localhost:8080 and see if you get a response.

If so, try going to the /bin folder and running shutdown.sh(.bat depending on your OS).

Comment: You will want to go to your installation directory, and once there, navigate to the bin/ subdirectory.  There should be a shutdown.sh file.  You can execute it by :
sh shutdown.sh

or

./shutdown.sh

You may need to precede it with sudo, depending on how you installed tomcat.

Comment: You may also find this article useful in the future!  I hope this helps.

http://code.google.com/p/gbif-providertoolkit/wiki/TomcatInstallationMacOSX#6)_Shut_down_Tomcat

Comment: If you are still unable to come to a solution, in terminal, you can execute ps -au to view all running processes.  Then you can locate the pid of the tomcat server, and execute a kill -9 <pid> to terminate the process.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the terminal and execute the command:

```sh
brew services stop tomcat
```

Post this.. dont start any services using "brew"

Run your application using *Run on Server*

If the state of the server is marked `stopped` then do the following:

Go to Window>Show View>Other
Select Server>Servers

In the console if you see `stopped, synchronized`, right click on the line where you see `stopped` and start the server